# Fast data migration on the same database

Tags: oracle, database-migration

I'm trying to find a way to perform a migration from two tables on the same database. This migration should be as fast as possible in order to minimize the downtime.

To put it on an example lets say I have a person table like so:

> **person_table** -> (id, name, address)

So a person as an Id, a name and an address. My system will contain millions of person registries and it was decided that the person table should be partitioned. To do so, I've created a new table:

> **partitioned_person_table**->(id,name,address,partition_time)

Now this table will contain an extra column called partition_time. This is the partition key for this table since this is a range partition (one partition every hour).

Finally, I need to find a way to move all the information from the *person_table* to the *partitioned_person_table* with the best performance.

- The first thing I could try is to simply create a statement like:

  INSERT INTO partitioned_person_table (id, name, address, partition_time)
    SELECT id, name, address, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM person_table;

The problem is that when it comes to millions of registries this might become very slow (also the temporary tablespace might not be able to handle all this information)

- My second approach was to use the ***EXCHANGE PARTITION*** method. Unfortunetly, I cannot do this because the tables contain diffrent column numbers.

Is there any other way that I can perfom this with the best performance (less downtime) ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered [online table redefinition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN11667)?

Comment: @AlexPoole thank you for your reply. I haven't heard about the Online Table Redefinition yet but are you sugesting to use this so that I can add the extra columns to the table to perform a partition exchange?

Comment: How big is it now?  You say "will contain millions of persons" which doesn't say how big today.

Comment: @tbone at the moment I have: 62 million rows (aprox. 82Gb) of information.

Comment: @AlexPoole I've been looking into the online table refefinition and that seems exactly what I need. The only problem is that my interim table will be the one containing the partition key (this key is not in the original one). Is it possible to do this or do I need to have my partition key on the original table as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with the state, that all the current records would be located in one partition (and your INSERT approach suggest that), you may only

1) add a new column  `partition_time` either as NULL or possible with  [metadata default only](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#sthref3958) - required 12c

2) switch the table to a partitioned table either with online redefinition (if you have no maintainace window, where the table is offline) or with exchange partition otherwise.

Comment: thank you for your reply. If I follow the Online Redefinition, what will happen to the information that is inserted when the migration is already in place ? Will Oracle automatically check that new information was inserted and that data will also be migrated? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is exact how [DBMS_REDEFINITION](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS042) works. Check in the docs the preconditions and how the changes are postponed and propagated.